# WiFi works on Ubuntu, but not wired connection

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, wired

I installed Ubuntu (server) onto a computer and during the setup I connected it to my wifi and it works fine. However I am trying to move it to a wired connection and it doesn't seem to recognize the connection.

sudo netplan -debug generate does not return any errors.

I know that the connection should work. It works when connected to my laptop and the light on the ethernet port on the back of the computer flashes when the computer is booting but then turns off when it finishes booting.

lshw returns:

```
 *-network DISABLED
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: 88E8056 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
            vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
            logical name: ens33
            version: 14
            serial: 00:21:97:0f:26:21
            capacity: 1Gbit/s
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
            resources: irq:26 memory:feafc000-feafffff ioport:e800(size=256) memory:feac0000-feadffff
```

ifconfig returns:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 1716  bytes 215593 (215.5 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1716  bytes 215593 (215.5 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0 
wlp3s1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.33  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::215:e9ff:fe4c:261  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:15:e9:4c:02:61  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 13520  bytes 4311598 (4.3 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 998  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 8205  bytes 5869540 (5.8 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

ip route:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s1 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.33 metric 600
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp3s1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.33
192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s1 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.33 metric 600
```

cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
version: 2 <--indentation in entire script is incorrect
renderer: networkd
wifis:
  wlp3s1:
     dhcp4: yes
     access-points:
       3MightyMen:                                                                                      
          password: 3346993030
ethernets:
  en33:  <--wrong, should be ens33:
    dhcp3: true <--wrong, should be dhcp4:
```

Comment: Routing problem?  Edit ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/1098790/edit ) your question and add in the results of  `ip route`

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: You have the indentation wrong, and you put en33 instead of the correct ens33. And dhcp3 should be dhcp4. That's why it doesn't work for you. Best to just copy/paste my .yaml script into your file. Please see my other comments below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your /etc/neplan .yaml file should look something like this... this will enable your ethernet device...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
    wifis:
      wlp3s1:
        dhcp4: yes
        dhcp6: no
        access-points:
          "3MightyMen":                                                                                      
          password: "3346993030"
    ethernets:
      ens33:
        dhcp4: yes
        dhcp6: no
# for a fixed IP, comment out the above line, (dhcp4: true),
# and uncomment addresses: and gateway4: lines below.
# to specify DNS nameservers, uncomment last three lines.
#       addresses: [192.168.1.20/24]
#       gateway4: 192.168.1.1
#       nameservers:
#         search: [mydomain, otherdomain]
#         addresses: [192.168.1.1, 1.1.1.1]
```

In `terminal`...

`sudo netplan --debug generate` # generate config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply current configuration

`reboot` # reboot and confirm proper network operation

*postnote: see https://netplan.io/examples for more examples*

Comment: lshw still says:*-network DISABLED

Comment: @EthanB you didn't copy/paste my .yaml script, and you've got errors in your manual edit of your .yaml file.

Comment: Once I copied it properly this worked. Thanks a ton, I'm getting download speeds that are 10x better now!